# Beamer: Changing the font size of the references using the shrink argument causes an error

Tags: beamer, biblatex, fontsize, apa-style

I'm trying to change the font size of the references using the shrink of the frame argument.
However, if I run this code:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=apa, backend=biber,doi,url]{biblatex}
\DeclareLanguageMapping{american}{american-apa}

\begin{filecontents}{literature.bib}
@article{foobar,
  Author = {An Author},
  Journal = {A Journal},
  Pages = {1--2},
  Title = {Some title},
  Volume = {1},
  Year = {1900}
}

\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{literature.bib}

\begin{document}

\frame{
  \textcite{foobar}
}

\frame[shrink=50]{
  \frametitle{References}
  \printbibliography
}

\end{document}
```

I get the following error:

```
! Arithmetic overflow.
\beamer@shrinkframebox ...\@tempdimc by\@tempcnta 
                                                  \relax \ifdim \@tempdimc >...
l.32 }

? 
! Emergency stop.
\beamer@shrinkframebox ...\@tempdimc by\@tempcnta 
                                                  \relax \ifdim \@tempdimc >...
l.32 }
```

If I remove the shrink argument it works.

I'm using TexLive 2011 on Debian Squeeze and I updated all my packages ;).

Comment: Test with `\frame[shrink=50,fragile]`, this often helps if you are doing complex stuff on your frame ;-)

Comment: Thanks for your help! With `\frame[shrink=50,fragile]` I get `Runaway argument? ! File ended while scanning use of \next.`

Comment: What happens if you change directly the font size, for example with `\tiny`?

Comment: The font size of the references stays the same.

Comment: Maybe `\renewcommand*{\bibfont}{\scriptsize}` will help.

Comment: It helped! If you add this solution as an answer, I can mark the question as solved.

Comment: Related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/57345/beamer-scaling-document-icons-in-the-bibliography

Answer (score 56, accepted):

I think `\renewcommand*{\bibfont}{\scriptsize}` will help!  ;)

Comment: Worked for me with biblatex!

Comment: Works for me with `biblatex` and option `[backend=biber]` also!

Answer (score 25):

I'm not using biblatex and André's answer did not work for me. I managed to achieve the result with the following:

```
\setbeamerfont{bibliography item}{size=\footnotesize}
\setbeamerfont{bibliography entry author}{size=\footnotesize}
\setbeamerfont{bibliography entry title}{size=\footnotesize}
\setbeamerfont{bibliography entry location}{size=\footnotesize}
\setbeamerfont{bibliography entry note}{size=\footnotesize}
```

In case it matters, I'm using the [`metropolis`](https://github.com/matze/mtheme) theme.

Comment: This worked for me with metropolis as well. I wonder if this can be achieved more concisely?

Answer (score 2):

I tried André's answer with no success. I found a work-around, if you need a quick solution:

1. Compile your beamer document including the bibliography (correct settings of citing/formatting style etc.).
2. open the `*.bbl` file and copy all its contents (`\begin{thebibliography} ...\end{thebibliography}`).
3. Paste it over the `\bibliograpy{yourbibfile}` command.
4. put a `\small` tag after `\begin{thebibliography}` for a smaller fontsize for your references!

As I said, its a quick way, if you don't want to fuss around. The downside being its complete absence of reactiveness to changes (`\...cite` commands) in your document.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! I've taken the liberty of editing your answer, to keep it in line with the site's style.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look on [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: Note that copy pasting bibliography is recommended for using bibtex with beamer