# beamer: Scaling document icons in the bibliography

Tags: beamer, bibliographies, scaling

Bibliographies can be typeset in a smaller font size by redefining the `\bibfont` macro (if one uses `natbib` or `biblatex`) or by simply appending the definition of `\thebibliography`. This also works with the `beamer` class; however, switching to a smaller font size leaves `beamer`'s document icons at the start of each bibitem unchanged. How can I scale those icons down to, say, 75% of their original size?

(From [Removing document icons from a Bibtex bibliography in Beamer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/53127/removing-document-icons-from-a-bibtex-bibliography-in-beamer), I gather that an answer is likely to involve some clever use of `\setbeamertemplate{bibliography item}`.)

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\apptocmd{\thebibliography}{\scriptsize}{}{}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{Bli74,
  author = {Blinder, Alan S.},
  year = {1974},
  title = {The economics of brushing teeth},
  journal = {Journal of Political Economy},
  volume = {82},
  number = {4},
  pages = {887--891},
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}

\nocite{*}

\bibliographystyle{plain}

\begin{frame}
\bibliography{\jobname}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Bibliography items are inserted using `\pgfuseimage`. You could redefine this before the bibliography and scale it the way you want to using commands from [`graphicx`](http://ctan.org/pkg/graphicx) (included by [`beamer`](http://ctan.org/pkg/beamer) by default:

```
\renewcommand{\pgfuseimage}[1]{\includegraphics[scale=.75]{#1}}
```

The above scales the image to 75% of its original size.

This should be issued *outside* the `frame` environment, before calling `\bibliography`. Here's your complete minimal example:

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}% http://ctan.org/pkg/beamer

\usepackage{etoolbox}% http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox
\apptocmd{\thebibliography}{\scriptsize}{}{}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{Bli74,
  author = {Blinder, Alan S.},
  year = {1974},
  title = {The economics of brushing teeth},
  journal = {Journal of Political Economy},
  volume = {82},
  number = {4},
  pages = {887--891},
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}

\nocite{*}

\bibliographystyle{plain}

\renewcommand{\pgfuseimage}[1]{\scalebox{.75}{\includegraphics{#1}}}

\begin{frame}
\bibliography{\jobname}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: MWE needs a little change for biblatex/biber, but also works with that. I have scaled the text way more and get a big gap. Compare [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/144807/74942) `\lower3.5pt\hbox{\hskip2pt\scalebox{2}{...}\hskip1pt}`; by this it ispossible to move the image up and (with negative values e.g.: `\hskip15pt ... \hskip-10`) also closer to the text. However, this does not change the lineskip for the first line in an entry, which differs from others in elongated items. I tried `[b]` on `scalebox`,`parbox` but it horribly failed (crashing not only TeXstudio). Hints?

Comment: Ok, can confirm. Tried it several times in my use case, but could not recreate the crash with this MWE (modified). I was using MacTeX and TeXstudio and tried to compile a similar file (with biblatex, though) including `\renewcommand{\pgfuseimage}[1]{\scalebox[b]{.75}{\includegraphics{#1}}}` (as my naive attempt at reducing the lineskip). **This led to a crash** of not only the editor, but moreover I was logged out of the session and -as crazy as it sounds- it changed some *JS Blocker* setting in Safari. **Where do I report this?**

Comment: @gr4nt3d: If you think there is an issue with [`beamer`](//ctan.org/pkg/beamer), you can [report it on Github](https://github.com/josephwright/beamer/issues).

Comment: well, I was asking which part of the process could have caused the crash (TeXstudio, pdflatex). Or could beamer alone be able to yield that? Apart from that: any hints on the lineskip?

Comment: Another small question concerning the scaling of the icon: As mentioned in a comment [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/68084/74942) I have used your method in combination with that biblatex code to automatically assign the icon. However, it does not scale the globe. Is there another command like `\pgfuseimage` that I have to replace for that?

Comment: @gr4nt3d: [This is the code associated with bibliography items](https://pastebin.com/4QH4C4zZ) ([source](https://github.com/josephwright/beamer/blob/master/base/beamerbaseauxtemplates.sty)). Both the the `book` and `online` (globe) elements use `\pgfuseimage`.

Comment: I am using [this modification](https://pastebin.com/EpPqAye2) on your code, with this [preamble](https://pastebin.com/V7TsFYzW), to achieve the [aforementioned symbol detection](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/68084/74942) but merely [the globes are not scaled](https://i.imgur.com/XYU3QLd.png). I have no idea why this should conflict with your solution. - **edit:** ok, I found a solution. I save the original command `\let\oldpgfuseimage\pgfuseimage` and use that one`{\scalebox{.5}{\oldpgfuseimage{#1}}}` instead of `\includegraphics{}`.