# Scaling bibitem symbols in beamer[poster]

Tags: beamer, bibliographies, scaling, beamerposter

Beamer has an option to draw a *cute little article icon* (official wording from the manual) next to each `\bibitem` when displaying the bibliography.

When using beamerposter, often this cute icon is a bit too little. Is there a way to scale it?

MWE:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
  \usepackage[orientation=portrait,size=a0,scale=1.4,debug]{beamerposter}

\usetheme{Berlin}

 \begin{document}
  \begin{frame}
  \begin{thebibliography}{9}
   \bibitem{}{Benner, Byers \newblock An arithmetic for matrix pencils: theory and new algorithms \newblock Numer. Math. 06}
  \end{thebibliography}
  \end{frame}
 \end{document}
```

Example: [image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to set the `bibliography item` template, which can be found in `beamerinnerthemedefault.sty`. The only modification I made to the default template is adding`scalebox`, of course you might use your favourite scaling method.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
  \usepackage[orientation=portrait,size=a0,scale=1.4,debug]{beamerposter}
\usetheme{Berlin}

\setbeamertemplate{bibliography item}{\lower3.5pt\hbox{\hskip2pt\scalebox{2}{\pgfuseimage{beamericonarticle}}\hskip1pt}}  %New code

 \begin{document}
  \begin{frame}
  \begin{thebibliography}{9}
   \bibitem{}{Benner, Byers \newblock An arithmetic for matrix pencils: theory and new algorithms \newblock Numer. Math. 06}
  \end{thebibliography}
  \end{frame}
 \end{document}
```

[image]