# How do I display the beamer bibliography icons?

Tags: beamer, bibliographies, icon

I am using and would like to use the bibliography icons as symbols. How do I pick them? It would be sufficient if it were as item icon in a list.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
\frame{\titlepage}
\begin{frame}
Print the article bibliography icon here or use it as item bullet in a list.
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Related: [beamer: Scaling document icons in the bibliography](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/57345/5764)

Answer (score 4):

Bibliography items are inserted using `\pgfuseimage` which is a wrapper for `\includegraphics`. The basic three items used in the bibliography include

- `beamericonarticle`
- `beamericonbook`
- `beamericononline`

To include these in your regular frames, either use `\pgfuseimage`, or scale the icons as needed with an explicit `\includegraphics`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
Print the article bibliography icon here or use it as item bullet in a list.

\begin{itemize}
  \item Article: \pgfuseimage{beamericonarticle}

  \item Book: \pgfuseimage{beamericonbook}

  \item Online: \pgfuseimage{beamericononline}

  \item[{\includegraphics[scale=.75]{beamericonarticle}}] An article
  
  \item[{\includegraphics[scale=.75]{beamericonbook}}] A book
  
  \item[{\includegraphics[scale=.25]{beamericononline}}] An online reference
\end{itemize}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Is there a way to use these icons if I am using `biblatex` to manage my references, or are they only valid for manually made bibliographies?