# Beamer Bibliography Icon

Tags: beamer, bibliographies

I want to list my references in a beamer presentation using `thebibliography` environment, with the nice little

- book icon (`\beamertemplatebookbibitems`) and
- article icon (`\beamertemplatearticlebibitems`)

in front of each source.

Is there an icon for websites too? something like `\beamertemplatewebsitebibitems`?
If not, is there a way to implement this easily ?

Answer (score 90, accepted):

There's the `online` option for the `bibliography item` template; an example showing the predefined options:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{thebibliography}{9}
\setbeamertemplate{bibliography item}[online]
\bibitem{A} ItemA
\setbeamertemplate{bibliography item}[book]
\bibitem{B} ItemB
\setbeamertemplate{bibliography item}[article]
\bibitem{C} ItemC
\setbeamertemplate{bibliography item}[triangle]
\bibitem{D} ItemD
\setbeamertemplate{bibliography item}[text]
\bibitem{E} ItemE
\end{thebibliography}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Of course, you can also use your own image(s):

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{thebibliography}{9}
\setbeamertemplate{bibliography item}{\includegraphics[width=1.5em]{ctanlion}}
\bibitem{A} CTAN lion drawing by Duane Bibby.
\end{thebibliography}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: when i compile your exact same code, i get an article icon instead of the online icon. the other icons are okay. no compilation error at all. i noticed that using [onlinee], [bookk] or [some_string] produces article icons as well without error messages. am i using an old version of some package ? i use Texmaker 3.3.4 on Win XP and MiKTeX 2.9.3888

Comment: And i think i have Biblatex installed, because when i type kpsewhich biblatex.sty to cmd.exe i get: C:/Program Files/Latex/Installation/tex/latex/biblatex/biblatex.sty

Comment: Workaround: got my own online icon (google) and included it like you described. perfect.

Comment: @Fry yes, if `online` doesn't give you the icon that appears in the image of my answer, you might have an old version of some package(s): update your system (MikTeX has a package manager for that (I don't use MikTeX)). My answer has nothing to do with `biblatex`; you are generating your bibliography without it as you said in your question, so my answer works independently of `biblatex`. Yes, as I mentioned in my answer, you can use your own images.

Answer (score 60):

With `biblatex` you can extend the `bibliography item` template to automatically select the appropriate icon.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[style=authoryear]{biblatex}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\setbeamertemplate{bibliography item}{%
  \ifboolexpr{ test {\ifentrytype{book}} or test {\ifentrytype{mvbook}}
    or test {\ifentrytype{collection}} or test {\ifentrytype{mvcollection}}
    or test {\ifentrytype{reference}} or test {\ifentrytype{mvreference}} }
    {\setbeamertemplate{bibliography item}[book]}
    {\ifentrytype{online}
       {\setbeamertemplate{bibliography item}[online]}
       {\setbeamertemplate{bibliography item}[article]}}%
  \usebeamertemplate{bibliography item}}

\defbibenvironment{bibliography}
  {\list{}
     {\settowidth{\labelwidth}{\usebeamertemplate{bibliography item}}%
      \setlength{\leftmargin}{\labelwidth}%
      \setlength{\labelsep}{\biblabelsep}%
      \addtolength{\leftmargin}{\labelsep}%
      \setlength{\itemsep}{\bibitemsep}%
      \setlength{\parsep}{\bibparsep}}}
  {\endlist}
  {\item}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}
\begin{document}
\nocite{glashow,markey,knuth:ct:a,knuth:ct:b,companion,bertram,ctan}
\begin{frame}[noframenumbering,plain,allowframebreaks]{References}
\printbibliography
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: How can we put two bibitems (that is in form of icons) horizontally after some spaces?

Comment: Wonderful! In the meantime, your code solved an issue I was having where the bib icons were bleeding over the left margin. I'm glad I came upon this while searching for something else. XD

Comment: @Audrey, wonderful solution! However, I am using a modification from [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/57352/74942) and [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/57341/74942) `\renewcommand*{\bibfont}{\tiny}
\renewcommand{\pgfuseimage}[1]{\lower-3pt\hbox{\hskip15pt{\scalebox{.5}{\includegraphics{#1}}}\hskip-10pt}}` and added `webpage` to your `\ifentrytype{online}`. With this setup, somehow the globe symbol is not scaled. How can I fix that?

Comment: Anyone having a similar issue and wondering: The solution was to switch the `\includegraphics{}`. I have described it [in a comment here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/57352/74942); together with an addition to include other web-sources `{\ifboolexpr{ test {\ifentrytype{online}} or test {\ifentrytype{webpage}}
       or test {\ifentrytype{url}} }`. Save the original command `\let\oldpgfuseimage\pgfuseimage` and use that one`\oldpgfuseimage{#1}` instead of `\includegraphics{#1}`.

Comment: You can get [the `biblatex-examples.bib` file](http://ctan.cs.uu.nl/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/examples/biblatex-examples.bib) from here.

Comment: Is it possible to have Beamer bibliography icon together with a numbering? For example: "Icon [1] Name. Book title, etc"?