# Beamer: Receiving information from Bibliography

Tags: beamer, bibliographies

I am using *Beamer*, and I prepare the *references* as follows.

```
\begin{thebibliography}{99}

\bibitem{refno} Author Name,
\newblock Title,
\newblock Location.

\end{thebibliography}
```

Is it possible to receive *authorname*, *title* or *location* just by *refno*?
Or is there any other simple way for this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your "crafted" `thebibliography` environment does not consist of fields like `author` and `title`, but simply of unlabeled strings separated by `\newblock`. Therefore, it is not possible to extract specific information. Instead, you must use packages like `biblatex` that resort to a bibliography database managed by backend programs like biber or BibTeX. Below, you'll find a compilable example using `biblatex` -- the `filecontents` package is used to "store" the `.bib` database within the example.

Make sure to compile the example using pdflatex -- biber -- pdflatex. If your editor doesn't handle this automatically, use the command line.

See section 3.7.7 of the `biblatex` manual for details about the `\citelist` command and its cousins `\citename` and `\citefield`. Note that some standard BibTeX field types are replaced with other types by `biblatex` (e.g. `journal` becomes `journaltitle`); while the old types work in the `.bib` file, you must use their `biblatex` equivalent within `\citefield`.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{biblatex}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{A01,
  author = {Author, A.},
  year = {2001},
  title = {Alpha},
  location = {Somewhere},
  publisher = {A publisher},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
As was shown by \citeauthor{A01} in \citeyear{A01} (published in
    \citelist{A01}{location})~\dots

\printbibliography
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: So it is not possible to get text between two `\newblock`s? But beamer can colour them separately.

Comment: My guess is that `beamer` uses certain colours e.g., for the first, second, ... last block (and makes implicit assumptions about the content of these blocks), but that doesn't equal being able to extract the information.

Comment: This does not produce the same output. What I get is "As was shown by A01 in A01 (published in A01 )...".

Comment: @bkarpuz You have to compile the example using (e.g.) pdflatex, then biber, the again pdflatex. (Such sequences are common if one uses backend programs like biber.)

Comment: I am using *WinEdt* and I could **not** figure this out.

Comment: @bkarpuz Change my example to `\usepackage[backend=bibtex]{biblatex}` and try to compile using pdflatex -- bibtex -- pdflatex. I'm fairly sure WinEdt allows to do *this* automatically.

Comment: How can I replace seperator *dots* in the bibliography with *commas*? (A. Author, Alpha, Somewhere: A publisher, 2001) I also want the book use `\beamertemplatebookbibitems`. Does this apply?

Comment: @bkarpuz Ad a) `\renewcommand*{\newunitpunct}{\addcomma\space}` Ad b) I don't know -- you should ask a new question and wait for a `beamer` expert to answer it.

Comment: The solution of the second one is located here http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/68080/beamer-bibliography-icon/68084#68084 By the way, I have `JOURNAL`, `VOLUME`, `YEAR`, `NUMBER` and `PAGES` information for my entry but why `\citelist{MR2000143}{JOURNAL}` does not call the value?

Comment: @bkarpuz See updated answer -- you'll have to use `\citefield` for these.

Comment: I fail. Do you mind showing me the code just for `JOURNAL`? So that I can modify it for my other purposes. Sorry to ask too much.

Comment: @bkarpuz That was just bad luck -- you need to use `\citefield{<key>}{journaltitle}`, because `biblatex` treats the `journal` field as an alias of its `journaltitle`. P.S.: If it works now, please accept my answer.