# Question about the Bibliography in Beamer

Tags: beamer, symbols

What is the command used to get the small red book symbol near the reference in the following image in a beamer document:

[image]

Please

Thank you

Comment: I edited my message i just want to know how to do to obtain the small bok near the reference thank you

Comment: [Beamer Bibliography Icon](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/68081)