# Logo creation in References

Tags: beamer

How to create this kind of logo in references?
I have done with other two logos in which picture of book and document is made , but got stuck here
[image: Logo]

Comment: You have been asking the same 1-sentence-long questions. Without a proper example, I'm not gonna touch your question. And I would kindly ask others to do the same.

Comment: @percusse, so possible duplicated?

Comment: @Sigur Same as in style, not as in content

Comment: Sir the code is very complex.

Comment: See [Beamer bibliography icon](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/68080/5764). You can obtain this image by using `\pgfuseimage{beamericononline}` inside [`beamer`](http://ctan.org/pkg/beamer).

Comment: It cannot be complex. You said you did the others. So make two slides long presentation, one slide for citing one slide for references and you are done.