# Replacing bibliography icons in beamer with biblatex bibliography

Tags: beamer, biblatex

[This Answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/68081/9736) shows how to use a user-defined icon when using the `thebibliography` environment. How can I redefine the icons if I use `\printbibliography` from biblatex?

Edit:

In the answer I linked to, each bibliography item is set manually, and so you can add

```
\setbeamertemplate{bibliography item}{\includegraphics[width=1.5em]{ctanlion}}
\bibitem{A} CTAN lion drawing by Duane Bibby.
```

in front of each seperate entry if you wanted to. With `\printbibliography` the whole bibliography is typeset. So if I were to say

```
\setbeamertemplate{bibliography item}{\includegraphics[width=1.5em]{ctanlion}}
\printbibliography
```

it would appear in front of the bibliography as a whole, not even in front of the first entry.

Comment: Isn't that described in the second answer to the question you linked to?

Comment: @Benjamin, I hope that makes the difference clearer. Or maybe I'm missing something.

Comment: I think you still haven't read the **other** answer: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/68084/30195

Comment: You're right, I missed it. However, this explains how you can assign the default icons to other entry types. I still don't know how to cobble the two answers together so that I have custom icons.

Comment: Do you want all entries to have the same custom icon? If not, how do you propose to tell `biblatex` which item gets which icon?

Comment: I don't want of all them to have the same icon. My idea, although I don't know how to implement it, was sort of two combine the two answers to the previous question. In the first answer, it is shown how to use a custom icon for a manual entry. In the second answer, the icons are typeset according to the biblatex entry type. Some sort of combination of the two should achieve what I want, no?

Comment: If you can tell me what you want, that might be possible, yes. But you need a way to tell `biblatex` which icon to pick for which entry. In the second answer for example you can simply replace the `\setbeamertemplate{bibliography item}[online]` bits by `\setbeamertemplate{bibliography item}{\includegraphics[width=1.5em]{ctanlion}}` to get your custom icon for `@online` entries. But you could also make sure that not the type but a `keyword` decides which icon to use. ... There are quite some ways to do that. What did you have in mind?

Comment: Please add a complete minimal example, complete with sample `.bib` entries. This will not only make it easier to help you, it will also make it more likely that the help you receive will actually be useful.

Comment: @moewe Sorry if I have been a bit thick, but your comment is what I was looking for. Maybe I was too tired, but I couldn't make that connection. Thanks. Post it as an answer and I'll accept.

Comment: Mhhh, now it is me being thick. I still don't quite know what you want. I think my comment doesn't add real value to the answers in the other question as of now. If you can explain what it is you want to do, I will happily create an answer.

Comment: Would you be OK with closing your question as a duplicate of [Beamer Bibliography Icon](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/68084/35864)?

Comment: Sure, no worries