# Incorrect citation format

Tags: beamer, bibtex, cross-referencing, apacite

My beamer presentation does not cite references as I want to. I want to have Name1 and Name2 (year). Currently I got (Name1 & Name2, year). Also on the references slide I want to have those icons before the article. I have many references so I would like to keep working with the bib file.

My bib file is (biblio.bib)

```
@article {ref1,
author = {Aa, Bb and Cc, Dd.},
title = {title},
journal = {journal},
volume = {1},
number = {1},
publisher = {publisher},
pages = {1--10},
year = {2017}
}
```

and the beamer latexcode is

```
%\documentclass[compress,black]{beamer}
\documentclass[handout]{beamer}

\usepackage{etex}
\usetheme{Szeged}
\useoutertheme[subsection=false]{smoothbars}

\usefonttheme{serif}

% include packages
\setbeamercovered{transparent}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{epsfig}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[all,knot]{xy}
\xyoption{arc}
\usepackage{undertilde}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{multimedia}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\ceil}{\lceil}{\rceil}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\setbeamercovered{dynamic}
\usepackage{apacite}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{hyperref}
%\usepackage{natbib}


\captionsetup[figure]{labelformat=empty}% redefines the caption setup of the figures environment in the beamer class.




% define your own colours:
\definecolor{Red}{rgb}{1,0,0}
\definecolor{Blue}{rgb}{0,0,1}
\definecolor{Green}{rgb}{0,1,0}
\definecolor{magenta}{rgb}{1,0,.6}
\definecolor{lightblue}{rgb}{0,.5,1}
\definecolor{lightpurple}{rgb}{.6,.4,1}
\definecolor{gold}{rgb}{.6,.5,0}
\definecolor{orange}{rgb}{1,0.4,0}
\definecolor{hotpink}{rgb}{1,0,0.5}
\definecolor{newcolor2}{rgb}{.5,.3,.5}
\definecolor{newcolor}{rgb}{0,.3,1}
\definecolor{newcolor3}{rgb}{1,0,.35}
\definecolor{darkgreen1}{rgb}{0, .35, 0}
\definecolor{darkgreen}{rgb}{0, .6, 0}
\definecolor{darkred}{rgb}{.75,0,0}
\definecolor{indigo}{rgb}{0.0, 0.25, 0.42}

\definecolor{lightgray}{gray}{1}
\definecolor{gainsboro}{rgb}{0.86, 0.86, 0.86}

\xdefinecolor{olive}{cmyk}{0.64,0,0.95,0.4}
\xdefinecolor{purpleish}{cmyk}{0.75,0.75,0,0}

% - I need a darkred background color in the sections bar (at the top) on all slides.
\setbeamercolor{section in head/foot}{bg=gainsboro!50!white}

% - Just beneath the sections bar I need a narrow darkblue bar on all slides.
\makeatletter
\AtBeginDocument{%
    \usebeamerfont{headline}%
    \colorlet{global.bg}{bg}%
    \pgfdeclareverticalshading{beamer@barshade}{\the\paperwidth}{%
       color(0ex)=(darkred);%
       color(1ex)=(darkred);%
       color(2ex)=(section in head/foot.bg);%
       color(7ex)=(section in head/foot.bg)%
    }
    \pgfdeclareverticalshading{beamer@aboveframetitle}{\the\paperwidth}{%
       color(0ex)=(darkred);%
       color(1ex)=(darkred);%
       color(2.5ex)=(section in head/foot.bg)%
     }
    \pgfdeclareverticalshading{beamer@belowframetitle}{\the\paperwidth}{%
      color(0ex)=(global.bg);%
      color(1ex)=(frametitle.bg)%
    }
    \fontsize{10}{12}\selectfont%
}

%Define box environment
\newenvironment<>{theorem}[1][\undefined]{%
\begin{actionenv}#2%
\ifx#1\undefined%
   \def\insertblocktitle{Theorem}%
\else%
   \def\insertblocktitle{Theorem ({\em#1})}%
\fi%
\par%
\mode<presentation>{%
  \setbeamercolor{block title}{fg=black,bg=gainsboro!50!white}
  \setbeamercolor{block body}{fg=black,bg=gainsboro!20}
}%
\usebeamertemplate{block begin}\em}
{\par\usebeamertemplate{block end}\end{actionenv}}

%Define box environment
\newenvironment<>{definition}[1][\undefined]{%
\begin{actionenv}#2%
\ifx#1\undefined%
   \def\insertblocktitle{Definition}%
\else%
   \def\insertblocktitle{Definition ({\em#1})}%
\fi%
\par%
\mode<presentation>{%
  \setbeamercolor{block title}{fg=black,bg=gainsboro!50!white}
  \setbeamercolor{block body}{fg=black,bg=gainsboro!20}
}%
\usebeamertemplate{block begin}\em}
{\par\usebeamertemplate{block end}\end{actionenv}}

\makeatother

% - Nothing should be displayed on the bottom bar of the slides (no authorname, no section, etc)
\setbeamertemplate{footline}{}

% - All text should be in black.
\setbeamercolor{title}{fg=black}
\setbeamercolor{frametitle}{fg=black, bg=white}

\title{title}

\author{Name}
%\date{}




\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    \titlepage
\end{frame}

\section{Introduction}
\subsection{Chapter 1}
\begin{frame}
   \cite{ref1}

\end{frame}

\section{References}
\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]
\frametitle{}
    {\bibliographystyle{apacite}}
    \bibliography{biblio}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: A couple of your previous questions don't have an accepted answer despite having one or more answers which seems to solve the questions. Can you have a look?

Comment: I still do not get icons on the references slide. Another problem is how the references are listed. For articles with multiple authors I have for example ',& last author' instead of '& last author'

Comment: see http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/68084/36296

Answer (score 2):

You should use `\citet` and `\citep` to get `Name1 (2016)` and `(Name1, 2016)` respectively.

Comment: Okay, it works with the package natbib. What remains is the listing of the references

Comment: What is going wrong with the references then? The representation of the references in the rendered bibliography?

Comment: yes, I want to have when listing the references those small pictograms for paper, book etc

Comment: Ah I see, so every reference is being prefixed with the correct icon for the several types. You could take a look at [this](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/68080/beamer-bibliography-icon)

Comment: It did not help.