# Add references in Beamer presentation

Tags: beamer

I want to add references in my beamer slides like this

[image]

I try as follows but it doen't compilate

```
\documentclass{beamer}
 \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
 %-----
 \usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts} %math
 \usepackage{graphicx}
 \usepackage{color}
  \usetheme{Madrid}

  \begin{document}

  \begin{frame}{}

  \beamertemplatearticlebibitems
 \begin{thebibliography}{10}
 \bibitem{V. M$\ddot{u}$ller, and A. Soltysiak}
 \alert{V. M$\ddot{u}$ller, and A. Soltysiak}
  \newblock  {Spectral radius formula for commuting Hilbert space operators}
  \newblock {\em Studia Math.103. (1992), 329-333}.
  \end{thebibliography}

 \beamertemplatearticlebibitems
 \begin{thebibliography}{10}
 \bibitem{M. Ch$\bar{o}$ and W. $\grave{Z}$elazko}
 \alert{M. Ch$\bar{o}$ and W. $\grave{Z}$elazko}
  \newblock  {On geometric spectral radius of commuting $n$-tuples of 
  operators}
 \newblock {\em Hokkaido Math. J., 21(2): 251-258, 1992}.
 \end{thebibliography}
   \end{frame}

 \end{document}
```

Comment: And where's the problem? You can do it with `thebibliography`, some bibliography tool or even differently, but we do not know what you tried and what you cannot reproduce.

Comment: I hope to get the codes

Comment: We are no do-it-for-me service. If you can't show us what you've tried so far, you won't get much help here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two problems:

- Don't use multiple `thebibliography` environments, but place all your bibitems in the same one
- You should not try to emulate umlauts  and other special characters with math symbols. For example ü should be written as `\"u` (or use babel for a shorter notation) I don't know which letters you tried to write in your second bibitem, so I just replaced them with o and Z, please look them up yourself.

Off-topic, but you don't need `\usepackage{graphicx}` and `\usepackage{color}` with beamer.

---

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
%-----
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts} %math
%\usepackage{graphicx}
%\usepackage{color}
\usetheme{Madrid}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}

\begin{thebibliography}{10}
\bibitem{mueller92}
\alert{V. M\"uller, and A. Soltysiak}
\newblock  {Spectral radius formula for commuting Hilbert space operators}
\newblock {\em Studia Math.103. (1992), 329-333}.

\bibitem{cho92}
\alert{M. Cho and W. Zelazko}
\newblock {On geometric spectral radius of commuting $n$-tuples of  operators}
\newblock {\em Hokkaido Math. J., 21(2): 251-258, 1992}.
\end{thebibliography}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: And one does not need to use complex, formatted, citation keys for bibitem…

Comment: Thank you for your answer.   If the reference is a book and not a paper. How can I do in order to distinguish between papers and books? please see the picture in my question.

Comment: @Student see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/68080/beamer-bibliography-icon