# How to change bullet style to numbers in Metropolis theme

Tags: beamer, bibliographies, beamer-metropolis

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usetheme[progressbar=frametitle]{metropolis}
\usepackage{appendixnumberbeamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[fragile]{Backup slides}
    Text \cite{Knuth92}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]{References}
  \bibliography{demo}
  \bibliographystyle{abbrv}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Does `\setbeamertemplate{bibliography item}[text]` help?

Comment: See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/68080/beamer-bibliography-icon

Comment: I added the `beamer` tag, seems appropriate

Comment: Thanks @TeXnician, that worked! I'm going to flag this as duplicate to the Q you referred to.