# Other Bibliography Symbols in Beamer

Tags: beamer, bibliographies

I make a presentation with Beamer and I would like to change the symbols before one bibitem. Now it looks like that:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

\frame{\frametitle{Literatur}
    \begin{thebibliography}{10} 
        \bibitem{1}
        Nathan Ida: Engineering Electromagnetics, Springer Spektrum, 2015, Third Edition
    \end{thebibliography}
}


\end{document}
```

[image]

How can I change it to a book or an "internet" symbol?

Thanks.

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/68080/beamer-bibliography-icon

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Beamer Bibliography Icon](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/68080/beamer-bibliography-icon)