# Change bibliography label in Beamer

Tags: beamer, bibtex

I am using

```
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{references}
```

to include references in the file *references.bib*. This is what I get
[image]
I want to change the icons one by one. In other questions they use

```
\setbeamertemplate{bibliography item}[article]
```

but this changes all the icons at once.

¿How can I change each icon individually? I want to put my own icon, not the default ones since they don't match the style of the presentation. Ideally without using *thebibliography* since I already have the file *references.bib*.

Comment: As it currently is, your question is unfortunately a bit unclear. Do you want all article type references to have the same icon and all book type references the same icon, but different from the article one? Or do you want each and every entry to get an entirely different icon? Please clarify.

Comment: Since you mention not wanting to use `thebibliography`, would be switching to `biblatex` be an option for you? (https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/68084/134144 might be helpful.)