# How to add icons to a bibliography?

Tags: bibliographystyle

The beamer documentclass adds icons before the items in the bibliography depending on their type (book, online, article, etc.).

[image]

How to achieve the same with the article documentclass?

Comment: Look at this https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/68084/231952 and this https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/68081/231952

Comment: I already did but `setbeamertemplate` is not available for article…